# Visual Studio Code hints and code highligh aren't working (Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pylint

Code highlighting and tooltips don't work for me in VSCode.

[It works in other languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf3Bb.png)

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you installed the Python and Pylance extensions for VS Code?

Comment: Yes, I've got Python extension pack, Pylance and IntelliSense